# SDL Web 8.1 | Old Httpupload support

Tags: 2013, httpupload, web8

We are working on a POC to upgrade our CMS from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 to SDL Web 8.1. We have currently 600+ web applications(.Net based) 2000+ publications running on current version. We have successfully installed Web 8.1 and upgraded some sites on Web 8.1, we have tested publishing with new Httpupload microservice through reverse routing and its works perfect but i want to explore if we can use old httpupload (Tridion 2013) by upgrading\replacing jars, dlls, configs etc.

Please suggest if we can upgrade old httoupload or its fully depreciated in Web 8.1.

Comment: If I understand your requirement properly, you want to enable the legacy publishing feature in web 8.1. Is it correct ?

Comment: i want to upgrade Httpupload used in Tridion 2013. don't want to install new httpupload based on microservice architecture.

Answer (score 5):

Publishing from 8.x to an untouched 2013 SP1 deployer should work just as is.

Don't upgrade your deployer at all - just keep it running as is, and try publishing.

8.x deployer is only available as a microservice, and requires discovery service, etc. Don't upgrade your database, don't upgrade your web applications - and things will work as is. If/when you want to upgrade the apps, you have to do it all at the same time *per environment*: Deployer, Database, Web app.

Comment: thanks for your inputs, what i understood from your comment.
we can go for staged upgrade -
Approach 1 - We can upgrade CM environment first and then complete CD environment i.e. Apps, deployer and other services in one go.
Approach 2- We can upgrade CD environment first (Apps, deployer, services etc.) and then CM environment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement properly, you want to use the legacy publishing feature instead of new publishing framework.

So answer is Yes! it is possible. Please the check this [document](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-A3758A5B-8623-4EC5-BC46-459B2E91E39C#docid=GUID-2B10C8D8-BB61-4CCE-98E7-A0F9AAF33929&filename=GUID-2B10C8D8-BB61-4CCE-98E7-A0F9AAF33929.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2B10C8D8-BB61-4CCE-98E7-A0F9AAF33929)

Comment: Tested sdlweb8.5 with old Httpupload and working fine without changes.